# How do I provide an HTML embedded code for my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, iframe, widget

I have a web page that I would like others to add onto their own web page. I know I can do this by providing an IFrame code, but is there a better way, such as providing a Javascript to embed? The IFrame has ugly scrollbars that do not make the embed so seamless. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What kind of content is it? Is it so wide that providing "scrolling='no'" in the iframe code won't both hide the scrollbars and show all the content on the third party site(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript, but it requires some special finessing with the document domain to handle cross-site scripting issues.

With CSS, it's possible to change how the iframe appears regarding scroll bars.

When we hosted a secured login control, we used a combination of an iframe and javascript with CSS to prevent scroll bars.